# Can't convert string array to double array properly, returns 0

Tags: c#, arrays, file

in the code above I'm trying to turn the string array that was made by reading all lines from a text file into a double array. However when I do that I print out each number in the double array they all print out saying

```
  0  
  0  
  0  
  0
```

When in the file the actual numbers are:

```
  -0.055
  -0.034      
  0.232      
  0.1756
```

I do not understand why it is doing this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You never assign a value to the array items, default value for `double` is zero

Comment: You never add anything to the `double` array though, you just create a new array with the same _length_

Comment: You are just creating and initializing double array. You are not putting any values in the array. That's why you are getting all zeros.

Comment: What code?  You deleted your code example in your last edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't `Parse` values from the file. It should be something like this:

```
 double[] test = System.IO.File
   .ReadLines(new_path)
   .Select(line => double.Parse(line)) // <- each line should be parsed into double
   .ToArray();

 foreach (double number in test) {
   Console.WriteLine(number);
 }         

 Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You never actually add any values to your `test` array. This line of code:

```
double[] test = new double[numberArray.Length];
```

Is just saying create a blank array, of `x` size.  The values inside that array with be the default (the default of `double` is `0`).  You need to assign values to the array if you want them to be there.

The easiest way to do convert your text file lines to a double array would be to use a little Linq:

```
if(File.Exists(newPath))
{
    double[] test = File.ReadLines(newPath).Select(x => double.Parse(x)).ToArray()
    foreach(double number in test)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number);
    }         
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The has the drawback of having no error handling though.

If you want to have error handling your code will just be a little longer, and you should create a `ParseLines()` method:

```
double[] test = ParseLines(newPath).ToArray()
foreach(double number in test)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}         
Console.ReadLine();
```

```
private static IEnumerable<double> ParseLines(string filePath)
{  
    if(File.Exists(newPath))
    {
        foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(newPath))
        {
            double output;
            if(double.TryParse(line, out output))
            {
                yield return output;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some good answers here. Here is another answer without Linq:

```
double parsedNumber;
for (int i = 0; i < numberArray.Length; i++)
{
    bool numberIsValid = double.TryParse(numberArray[i], out parsedNumber);

    if (numberIsValid)
        test[i] = parsedNumber; 
    else
        Console.WriteLine($"{numberArray[i]} is not a valid double.");
}
```